# Regex check first occurence as @/# and second as A-Za-z0-9 in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want an regex that will test the string should contain first character as @/# and second should be alphabet or number.And @/# should not be repeated.
for:
string could be @abc

## fjrgj

but it cannot be lvfl
124454/ #@# / #!@ / #!@!

Comment: https://regex101.com/#javascript FYI, this as nothing to do with jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(@|\/|#){1}\w+$

^             # start
(@|\/|#){1}   # match any one character of ==>@ or / or # 
\w+           # match 1 or more of alphabets or digits or _
$             # end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex based on negative lookahead:

```
/^[@\/#]\w+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC2hG8/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^             # start
[@\/#]        # match @ or / or #
\w+           # match 1 or more of alphabets or digits or _
$             # end
```

Comment: I want that the string should contain only alphabet/number and _ only after @/#